# Macro concatenation, function name generation

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

```
#define Map(From, To, val)          \
        Map__##From__##To(val)


Map(TYPEA, TYPEB, 22);
```

In the above code I am wondering why `Map(TYPEA, TYPEB, 22);` is getting expanded to  `Map__From__TYPEB(22);` and not `Map__TYPEA__TYPEB(22);`

I used gcc -E for expansion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `From__` is not a token in `Map` and hence, preprocessor does not look it up.. fix is :

```
#define Map(From, To, val) \
        Map__##From##__##To(val)
```

Comment: It works fine, but I have not understood the reason yet, can you please point me to some literature that could explain me the diff between ##From## and ##From ?

Comment: its about understanding the basic principle @LOK, its simple - `From` is a token that can be substituted.. where-as `From__` is not a token that can be substituted. The substitutable tokens are in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
"#define ZERO 0" != "#define ZERO 0_"
```

Similarly, in your snippet, `From != From_` and thus is not replaced.
The working solution is already provided by @Aniket.